# Работа с git через одни и те же ключи в windows и mac

Tags: mac, git, ssh, контроль-версий

При переходе с windows на mac скопировал папку .ssh с ключами (id_rsa и id_rsa.pub). При попытке работы с git, происходит ошибка. В чем может быть причина?

Comment: Возможно сброшены параметры доступа к папке .ssh
http://www.howtogeek.com/wiki/Fixing_%22WARNING:_UNPROTECTED_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE!%22_on_Linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ключ должен быть формата openSSH-key, а добавить ключ

```
ssh-add
```

Ключ, сгенерированный путти, не является форматом openSSH-key, но в нём можно его переконвертировать.

Comment: И поменять пути в файле config (IdentityFile, например).

Comment: Ключ не является форматом openSSH-key...